# Realtime уведомление

Tags: php, javascript, realtime

Доброго времени суток, ребят подскажите как можно реализовать такую функцию:

- человек заполняет форму
- после отправки данных с формы, у модератора, у которого открыта страница с заявками, появляеться новая заявка в риалтайме, он может ее подтвердить
- в это время у пользователя который заполнял форму идет таймер, например 2-3 минут, и написано типа "Заявка рассматривается модератором"
- после того как модератор подтвердил заявку, у пользователя realtime показываеться надпись что его завяка прошла модерацию.

Подскажите схему или библиотеки которые стоит рассмотреть.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Аяксом обрабатываешь форму. Заявка пишется в таблицу. На странице модератора идет постоянный опрос этой таблицы, при появлении новой записи, отображаешь заявку. После ее подтверждения модератором обновляешь запись. На странице юзера при получении ответа от модератора показываешь сообщение.

из инструментов что больше нравится - jQuery, Vue.js, Angular

Comment: Либо используя websocket - так как опрашивать постоянно через ajax какое-то endpoint API - это костыль.